# Move Reviews outside of Tabs - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, review, woocommerce-theming

I haven't had any luck with the answers posted here. All I want to do is place woocommerce "reviews" outside of the premade woocommerce tabs (description, reviews, and additional information)

I know how to remove the reviews just fine with

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );
function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );      // Removes reviews
    return $tabs;
}
```

Now I want to add that back out somewhere different (outside of the tab area)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/#tab-description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it depend on where you want to output it. After you decide where you want to output it then use `comments_template()` function.

For example if you want to output it `after product summary` section, then you could do something like this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'your_theme_review_replacing_reviews_position', 21 );

function your_theme_review_replacing_reviews_position()
{
  comments_template();
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs )
{
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```

Or you could hook it somewhere else like all the way down the page using `woocommerce_after_single_product`, like so:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'your_theme_review_replacing_reviews_position');

function your_theme_review_replacing_reviews_position()
{
  comments_template();
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs )
{
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```

Both examples are tested and work. Let me know if you were able to get it to work!

Comment: This worked great! I had a lot of luck with the first example, for some reason I couldn't get the second one working, cheers!